# How to write WPF DataTrigger within Border Style and how to Find Element in Setter?

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger

I need a WPF DataTrigger for the Mouse Hover functionality of a Border. The Border Contains a Button, initially its Visibility is Collapsed. The Button should be Visible only on Mouse Hover otherwise Collapsed.

```
<Border Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFF2FFC6" Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <Button x:Name="btn" Content="iApp" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="btn" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

> Note: I need only DataTrigger. Don't suggest Event Trigger.

Here I Can't able to find the TargetName, it produces the Build Error "**Error  1   The name "btn" is not recognized**"

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with the border here?

Comment: You can use `TargetName` property if you create ControlTemplate for the your element. In your case you can use `Binding` for the `Button` `Visibility` property with `ValueConverter` insted.

Comment: Initially I paced a Grid, its show me an error, So, I changed it to Border. If you want to replace with any other frame you can change it. I need a Box, within a Box, I need that Button.

Comment: Also, `Visibility="Collapsed"` will hide the control and the allocated space.  Make use of `"Hidden"` . . [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I Know. But in my main project, I need a DataTrigger. This is a sample source code. In my main project, I Created the Button in dynamic. So, I can't able to give Visibility Binding.

Comment: Here the Problem is TargetName raises an error. Kindly give your solution for the error pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TragetName cannot be used in Style.Triggers. It should be used in ControlTemplete.Triggers.
2. You can write code like this(Not test).

Add the namespace in you xaml

```
     xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:yours coverter's namespace"
```

Add the converter in your resources

```
     <UserControl.Resources>
           <converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
     </UserControl.Resources>
```

This is your border:

```
     <Border x:Name="m_Border" Margin="0,20,0,0">
     <Button x:Name="btn" Content="iApp"  Visibility="{Binding  IsMouseOver,ElementName=m_Border,Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=Normal}"}" />
    </Border>
```

3. Using this converter

   ```
     public enum BooleanToVisibilityConverterType
     {
           /// <summary>
           /// Normal
           /// </summary>
           Normal = 1,

           /// <summary>
           /// Reverse
           /// </summary>
           Reverse = 2
      }

     public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
     {
           public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
           {
                var targertValue = false;

            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("BooleanToVisibilityConverter - Convert Error");
            }
            else if (!Boolean.TryParse(value.ToString(), out targertValue))
            {
                throw new Exception("BooleanToVisibilityConverter - Convert Error");
            }
            else
            {
                var parameterValue = BooleanToVisibilityConverterType.Normal;

                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    Enum.TryParse<BooleanToVisibilityConverterType>(parameter.ToString(), out parameterValue);
                }

                if (parameterValue == BooleanToVisibilityConverterType.Reverse)
                {
               return targertValue ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    return targertValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;                    
                }
            }
        }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
       var targetValue = Visibility.Collapsed;

       if (value == null)
       {
           throw new Exception("BooleanToVisibilityConverter - ConvertBack Error");
       }
       else if (!Enum.TryParse<Visibility>(value.ToString(), out targetValue))
       {
           throw new Exception("BooleanToVisibilityConverter - ConvertBack Error");
       }
       else
       {
           var parameterValue = BooleanToVisibilityConverterType.Normal;

           if (parameter != null)
           {
               Enum.TryParse<BooleanToVisibilityConverterType>(parameter.ToString(), out parameterValue);
           }

           if (parameterValue == BooleanToVisibilityConverterType.Reverse)
           {
               return targetValue == Visibility.Visible ? false : true;
           }
           else
           {
               return targetValue == Visibility.Visible ? true : false;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Kindly send the Full XAML Source Code including the Static Resource Key Declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`TargetName` is mostly used within control templates and not simply within styles.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.targetname(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You can set this property to the name of any element within the scope
>   of where the setter collection (the collection that this setter is
>   part of) is applied. This is typically a named element that is within
>   the template that contains this setter.

Also, to achieve your need, you should set trigger to `Button` not for `Border`

```
   <Border x:Name="border" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFF2FFC6" Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="iApp" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" >
            <Button.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Border>
```